# Android crashing with java.lang.stackoverflowError

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

I'm implementing a program that should calculate from Celsius to Fahrenheit and otherwise. But if I start the program, it crashes up when I click on button "calculate". In the Java I get following error, when a method is start at line 72

[image]

```
627  627 com.example.ubersatzer AndroidRuntime FatalException: main
627  627 com.example.ubersatzer AndroidRuntime java.lang.StackOverflowError
627  627 com.example.ubersatzer AndroidRuntime at.come.example.ubersatzer.InputFragment.isConvertFromCelsiusToFahrenheit (InputFragement.java:72)
```

here is the code from the activity class, the relevant methods:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.buttonConvert:
        convert(); 
        break;
    }
}


private void convert() {
            if (inputFragment.isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit()) {
        doConvertFromCelsiusToFahrenheit();
    }
}

private void doConvertFromCelsiusToFahrenheit(){
    String celsiusStringValue = inputFragment.getCelsiusValue();
    double celsiusValue = Double.parseDouble(celsiusStringValue);
    double fahrenheitValue = ((celsiusValue * 9) / 5 ) + 32;
    outputFragment.setOutput(String.valueOf(fahrenheitValue) + "F");
}
```

And here the code of isConvertFromCelsiusToFahrenheit()  of class InputFragment.java

```
    public boolean isConvertFromFahrenheitToCelsius() {
                if (inputFahrenheit.getText() != null
                && inputFahrenheit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public boolean isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit(){
        return !isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit();
    }
```

Comment: post relevant snippet of code

Comment: I am suspecting a recursive method with improper exit

Comment: don't post snapshot of logcat.. Post it as text in your question

Comment: The "relevant snippet of code" @blackbelt refers to is the code of the `isConvertFromCelsiusToFahrenheit()` method.

Comment: can you post code of this method `InputFragment.isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit()`

Answer (score 5):

here is your problem

```
   public boolean isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit(){
        return !isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit();
    }
```

method `isConvertFromCelsiusToFahreinheit` is recursively calling itself

Comment: lol thanks :) i see . very lol failure of me. THanks mates, very nice here and very fast support :)

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, there is a recursive call at line 72 of InputFragment.java. Just make sure this one terminates.